# How to use emoji in android app on button click in Edit Text and How create my own emoji programmatically?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

How to use emoji in android app on button click in Edit Text and How create my own emoji pro grammatically?

i am making an android app of dairy in which i am using emoji in my app but i am unable to set emoji on button click to select an emoji from emoji list and set that selected emoji in edit text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconTextView
android:id="@+id/emojicon_text_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
emojicon:emojiconSize="28sp"/>
```